# How can I remove the strange white margin around my .png (plotted with r, ggplot)?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, png, margin

I save plots with ggplot as .png. The background has to be black, but there is allways a small white margin (only top, down an left; not right).

How can I remove this margin?

Thank you!

Here is my Code

```
library(ggplot2)
require(grid)


dat <- data.frame("xvar"=runif(500, 1, 10), 
              "yvar"=runif(500, 1, 10))

n <- 1
for(i in 1:n){
png(file=paste("green", i, ".png", sep=""), width=400, height=400)
  x <- sample(500, 50)
  i <- ggplot(data=dat[x,], aes(x=xvar, y=yvar))+
geom_point(col="green", size=3,shape=15)+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
     panel.grid.major=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=
     element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(), plot.background=element_rect(fill="black"), 
    panel.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"), plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))+
  scale_x_continuous()
print(i)
dev.off() }
```

[image: Example]

[image]

Comment: i don't see it; have you tried other devices (eg pdf, cairo_png, quartz_png, etc.?)

Comment: +1 for good first question on SO, including reproducible data and code. I also am seeing a white margin using R 2.15.3 on Windows 7 x64, on left and bottom sides of the png image. Not sure what is causing it though.

Comment: The margin is really small (~ 1 pix). I have the same problem with all devices.

Comment: I'm using win 7 x64, R 3.0.0 and R-Studio 0.97.449.

Comment: I see it as well (or at least, something) on OSX R 3.0.0. I added a clearer picture of what I see in the lower left. Feel free to remove it if it doesn't reflect what you're asking about.

Comment: In my case, it is a white line. It can be seen when clicking right on my picture and open it in a new windows.

Comment: This fix works on my setup: `plot.background=element_rect(fill="black", colour=NA)`

Comment: @bdemarest Can you make that an answer so that we can up-vote it and Markus can accept it (so we all know it is solved)?

Comment: For me, at least, the issue was axis tick length, even though the ticks were set to element_blank. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623228/5009249) here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The line you are seeing is the default outline colour of the `plot.background` rectangle element. You can remove it by setting colour to NA in your `theme()` call:

```
theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="black", colour=NA))
```